# Qt Regular expression to split string between [ ]

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I want to split a string `[A ] [B 1] [C 2] [D 254] [E 0]`

into `[A ]`, `[B 1]`, `[C 2]`, `[D 254]` and `[E 0]`.

I have tested the expression `\[(.*?)\]` online which is working fine, but I am not able to split it using `QRegExp`. The code is given below.

```
    QRegExp rx("\[(.*?)\]"); //RegEx for [----]
    QString str("[A ] [B 1] [C 2] [D 254] [E 0] ");
    QStringList query = str.split(rx);
    for( auto q : query ) {
        qDebug() << q;
    }
```

Can anybody point out where I am making the mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Use the regex `\[(.*?)\]` to match, not split.

Comment: How can I split using this match expression?

Comment: `"\\[|\\]"` using this splits but delimiters are not captured, and `spaces` also get captured

Comment: `"\\[|\\] "` worked for me thanks. although i wasn't able to include delimiters.

Comment: @Tushar That type of regular expression can be problematic if any of his entries contain square brackets. In this case it is probably fine, because it looks like his data is strictly: `[ Letter Number ]`. But if it were `[String Number]`, an entry such as this: `[foo\] 37]` will cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to split this string properly are **"lookaheads"** and **"lookbehinds"**.

```
QString s("[A ] [B 1] [C 2] [D 254] [E 0]");
QStringList sl = s.split(QRegularExpression("(?<=\\])[ ](?=\\[)"));
```

Tossing that into a `qDebug() << sl;` gave me this:

[image]

Lets break it down:

- `(?<=\\])` or `(?<=PutTextHere)`is a **"positive lookbehind"**, which will see if the string behind it matches, but not include it in the match itself.
- `[ ]` This could just simply be an empty space:  -- I just include the square brackets for readability.
- `(?=\\[)` or `(?=PutTextHere)`is a **"positive lookahead"**
- `\\[` The reason why you need two escapes, is that the regular expression needs one escape `\`, and your code will need to escape the escape. An alternative would be:
  `QStringList sl = s.split(QRegularExpression("(?<="
                         + QRegularExpression::escape("]")
                         + ")[ ](?="
                         + QRegularExpression::escape("[")
                         + ")"));`

Comment: Thanks for nice explaination. @akiva

Answer (score 0):

`"\\[|\\] "` can split the enclosed `[ITEM]`.